# 投资 vs 投入 - investing / investments?

Tags: vocabulary

Okay, here is what I have so far:

投资 is either a verb meaning to invest money in something, or an equivalent noun meaning investment, but it is always monetary.

投入 on the other hand can also have the meaning of 投资, but it can have additional meanings too, however it is these additional meanings that are eluding me.

Can anyone please give a brief rundown of the main extra non-monetary-investment meanings of 投入?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can anyone please give a brief rundown of the main extra non-monetary-investment meanings of 投入?*

When the object is not money, 投入 doesn't mean to invest money

main meanings of 投入:

1. "deploy". Example: 投入三百人的警力 (deploy a police force of 300 people)
2. "throw in" . Example: 把球投入籃中 (throw the ball into the basket)
3. "immerse" Example: 投入工作 (immerse in work)

reference: http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/9015/

Comment: Oh, that is brilliant. Thanks again Tang!

Comment: And thanks for sharing the website link - I will add that to my research-source list